# Change in html file does not take effect when I restart tornado server

Tags: python, caching, tornado, eol

I'm starting to learn Tornado and going through the [Intro to Tornado](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021292.do) book.

While working through one of the examples, I had a missing quote in an HTML file and got the following error:

> File "modules/book_html.generated.py", line 11
>       if book["subtitle] != "":  # modules/book.html:3
>   SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

This is what book.html looks like:

```
<div class="book">
  <h3 class="book_title">{{ book["title"] }}</h3>
  {% if book["subtitle"] != "" %}
        <h4 class="book_subtitle">{{ book["subtitle"] }}</h4>
    {% end %}
  <img src="{{ book["image"] }}" class="book_image"/>
    <div class="book_details">
      <div class="book_date_released">Released: {{ book["date_released"]}}</div>
      <div class="book_date_added">Added: {{ locale.format_date(book["date_added"], relative=False) }}</div>
      <h5>Description:</h5>
        <div class="book_body">{% raw book["description"] %}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added the missing quote, restarted the server (running on localhost) and still got the same error. Copy-pasted code exactly from [book's github](https://github.com/Introduction-to-Tornado/Introduction-to-Tornado/tree/master/extending_templates/bookstore), still same error. Commented out the entire file, same thing. Replaced the entire code (all files, main.py, everything in templates folder, everything) with the code from github, same thing. 
It looks like Chrome is caching the file or something, but I even changed the filename to book2.html, and the error came out with the changed file name:

> File "modules/book2_html.generated.py", line 11
>       if book["subtitle] != "":  # modules/book2.html:3

I tried clearing the cache, no luck. I went to Chrome's developer tools and checked the Disable cache checkbox, same. I also tried running the web app in Firefox and same thing.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that tornado caches the templates as well. Taken from their [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/template.html)

> Loader is a class that loads templates from a root directory and caches the compiled templates:

So if your calling loader it might be your issue.

Comment: Fixed. I passed debug=True in the Application constructor as per the [doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#debug-mode-and-automatic-reloading) and it worked. Thanks for the help!